# Chrome extension: Error: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, in my background.js file, the following code seems to trigger an error in my console.log on the launch of chrome.

"Error in event handler: Typeerror: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')"

The code in question is the following:

```
chrome.tabs.onHighlighted.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    let url = tab.url;
```

The error doesn't occur AFTER I have loaded other tabs, only on the initial load of chrome. I think this indicates my background script is running before the URL is available in the very first loaded tab.

I have attempted using if(tab.url) but the error still flags.

Is there a way to ignore the code if the url is undefined or another easy way to fix?

---

Manifest.json as requested:
...

```
"manifest_version": 3,
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "cookies",
    "notifications",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
],
```

...

Comment: You should at least post your `manifest.json`.

Comment: You've invented non-existent parameters. Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onHighlighted) to see the real ones.

Comment: @Mephisto123 - I'm curious where you got the non-existent parameter syntax. Did you use ChatGPT to generate the code, or did you copy the parameters from chrome.tabs.onUpdated ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get around it by using optional chaining, e.g. `chrome.tab?.url`. That will at least prevent the error you mentioned. But in order to properly help you need to share more code, preferably including your manifest.json file